# How to disable noise suppression on Realtek ALC887?

Tags: debian, audio, pipewire

> The ALC887 is a 7.1 Channel High Definition Audio Codec with two
> independent SPDIF outputs. Featuring eight channels of DAC support 7.1
> sound pla yback, and integrates two stereo ADC that can support a
> stereo microphone, and feature Acoustic Echo Cancellation (AEC), Beam
> Forming (BF), and Noise Suppression (NS) for voice applications.

I'd like to stream music with Pipewire (easyeffects) to Zoom on Debian testing.

When I tested my mic on the website mictest but there is a notification that noise suppression is on. It also sounds like that might be. Could it be possible to disable that somehow without messing up my audio ?